# Windows batch file execution log

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am executing a batch file in windows as below:

EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL "\remote-drive\temp.bat"

How can I find out when was the last time this file was executed, how long it took to completely execute or any other information?

p.s. I cannot edit the batch file in any way.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Forgot to mention..I cannot use windows task scheduler as well :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't run it directly; build another batchfile to run it. Something like:

```
@echo off
>>mylogfile.txt echo started at %date% %time% 
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL "\remote-drive\temp.bat"
>>mylogfile.txt echo finished at %date% %time%
```

I don't understand `EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL "\remote-drive\temp.bat"`
If you want to run a batchfile, you should use `call batchfile.bat`

Answer (score 0):

SQL? Modified [Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33554722/3439404): don't run it directly; build another batchfile `temp_with_log.bat` to run it. Something like:

```
@echo off
>>mylogfile.txt echo started at %date% %time% 
call "\remote-drive\temp.bat"
>>mylogfile.txt echo finished at %date% %time%
```

and run the following command

```
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL "\remote-drive\temp_with_log.bat"
```

If the `"\remote-drive\temp.bat"` contains [`EXIT` command](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) without `/B` switch, use  `start "" /W cmd /C` instead of `call` as follows:

```
@echo off
>>mylogfile.txt echo started at %date% %time% 
start "" /W cmd /C "\remote-drive\temp.bat"
>>mylogfile.txt echo finished at %date% %time%
```

Comment: Maybe `EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL '"\remote-drive\temp_with_log.bat"'`. Not sure about proper using single and double quotes.